# POD error when trying to use Webstorm for React Native iOS development

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, webstorm

I am new to React Native and iOS App development. I come across the following error when I try to run an new reactive native project for iOS:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli run-ios
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "untitled3.xcodeproj"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -project untitled3.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme untitled3 -destination id=CAE67ED1-8877-47D6-826E-376DD2D45250")
................
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project untitled3.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme untitled3 -destination id=CAE67ED1-8877-47D6-826E-376DD2D45250

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the untitled3 editor. (in target 'untitled3' from project 'untitled3')
PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'untitled3' from project 'untitled3')
    cd /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh
Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!

CompileC /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'untitled3' from project 'untitled3')
    cd /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DFB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/main.m -o /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
In file included from /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/main.m:3:
/Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'untitled3' from project 'untitled3')
    cd /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DFB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/untitled3-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
In file included from /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.m:1:
/Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/davep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/untitled3-adqqamxzcxmswnfnvithzulzjaop/Build/Intermediates.noindex/untitled3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/untitled3/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening untitled3.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I already install the following:
* XCode
* React Native CLI

May I know what could be going wrong? It seems the Pod install could be a problem?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: `error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/davep/WebstormProjects/untitled3/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?` - did you?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

As I create the project and run it inside Webstorm so the error happens. It seems the Pod install was not run during the compilation.... I try to recreate the project using the command line and everything works now

Answer (score 1):

The project was created and run inside Webstorm. It seems the error will be gone after I run the project in the command line directly. During the process, RN will ask me to install cocopads.

Many thanks for all the comment!